Mandos client not encrypting on boot after upgrade
I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 23.10 to 24.04. Before upgrade I had a functional mandos-client running on the machine which receives a secret from a running mandos server on another machine.
After upgrade it was not working anymore. With a screen attached I got the following error message during boot: gpg: No Secret Key
I needed to encrypt it manually. After login I checked that the keys are still in /etc/keys/mandos. They are.
I also removed the client and installed it again which also updated the initrd image.
The mandos server is working and providing the secret. I checked this.
But in /etc/crypttab there is no keyscript.
Old mandos manpages are referring to a method to test with running mandos-client but this is not working. There is no mandos client binary.
How can I now check or further debug that it is working? Problem is that I'm currently only able to login remotely and not with a screen attached. So I can not do trial and error.

From your question. (After upgrade it was not working again) You say again has it broke before?

@DavidDE Yes, it worked before flawless. Bad English. It should be "It was not working". Sorry. Corrected it.

I had a similar problem and during my research in the Mandos mailing list I came across a thread from May 16: Mandos-client failing when run inside initramfs of Ubuntu 24.04 

The issue is that the gpg-agent and gpgconfig binaries are not being included in the initramfs under ubuntu 24.04.  That stems from the fact that the libgpgme11 library has been renamed in 24.04 to libgpgme11t64.  Because of that, the initramfs hook  /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/mandos doesn’t work correctly.  Specifically, like 183 of that script:
libgpgme11_version="dpkg-query --showformat='${Version}' --show libgpgme11”
That line returns an empty string under Ubuntu 24.04 but works correctly under 22.04.  It then doesn’t match the logic conditions later on, and the gig utilities do not get included.  A simple fix that allows it to work on both Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04 would be to just add an asterisk at the end of that line:
libgpgme11_version="dpkg-query --showformat='${Version}' --show libgpgme11*”

That fixed it for me. Maybe it will also help you
